# Assembly not available error

Tags: c#, monodevelop

I'm sorry if this is an ultra-noobish question, but I've never tried my hand at C# development before and this seems to be a really simple problem that I just can't find the solution for.

I'm trying to build Banshee player from source. The references gio-sharp, gkeyfile-sharp, glib-sharp, gtk-sharp, gtk-sharp-beans and libgudev (possibly some others, I'm only listing from one source file at the moment) all give me an "Assembly not available for Mono / .NET 3.5 error (in Mono 2.10.5) error" when I open the solution file in Monodevelop. I'm new to C# so I don't know what the hell is going on, but it looks like these are the C# equivalent of java imports, and they're supposed to be included in the mono equivalent of the "classpath", but I can't figure out how to.

I've got all the packages installed in ubuntu, but none of them show up in the "Edit References" dialogue when I try to select it.

EDIT: No answers yet? I thought there was going to be an obvious fix. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need some dev packages, which would include the .pc files that register those assemblies with pkgconfig so the IDE can discover them.

Comment: No, all dev packages are installed, but it still won't find it. For example, gtk-sharp has a (populated) directory in /usr/lib/mono/gac/ but in monodevelop it still gives me an "Assembly not available for..." error. I have no idea what to do. This problem is driving me crazy!

Comment: The GAC is for runtime, not compile time. A search on the Ubuntu pacakges site turns up lots of -cil-dev packages like 'libgtk2.0-cil-dev', do you have those?

Comment: Yes, I had all the cil-dev packages. I've sorted out my problem with the banshee developers, apparently I was supposed to be compiling the package with the CLI 4.0 runtime, rather than the default. I'm not sure what this translates into in monodevelop, but I typically avoid IDEs anyway, so it doesn't bother me. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: They should fix their projects then. Project Options->Build->General, set Target Framework to 4.0.

Comment: mhutch' tip solved the problem for me: Options->Build->General, set Target Framework to 4.0